# How to support variable interpolation in web.xml?

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm packaging a web application and tomcat into a zip file. This zip should be able to use in any location or path.
This web application require to load an additional folder (response-folder) to be able to startup. 
Due to the zip can be unzip anywhere, I need to find out my current path when the server is started and set the path in the startup.bat.

The following is my zip folder structure:

```
my.zip
    - apache-tomcat
        - bin
            - startup.bat
        - webapp
            - mywebapp
                - WEB-INF
                    - web.xml
    - response-folder
```

In my startup.bat, I had the following line

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Dapache-tomcat-current-folder="%TOMCAT_CURRENT_FOLDER%"
```

I would like achieve something like below:

```
<servlet>
    <description>MyService</description>
    <display-name>MyService</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MyService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.my.package.MyService</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>Folder that contains response files</description>
        <param-name>RESPONSE_FOLDER</param-name>
        <param-value>${apache-tomcat-current-folder}\response-folder</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Note: I'm not able to the change the web application java code, as the web application is not belong to me.

May I know is there anyway to make web.xml to support variable interpolation or achieve behavior such as above?
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

To use environment variables in web.xml, you can add

```
set "CATALINA_OPTS=-Dapache-tomcat-current-folder=somevalue"
```

or if you want to reference a System environment variable

```
set "CATALINA_OPTS=-Dapache-tomcat-current-folder=%apache-tomcat-current-folder%"
```

in `bin/setenv.bat` (`bin/setenv.sh` for *nix). 
You need to create this file.